# servlet not running on tomcat v6.0.35 and eclipse helios

Tags: servlets

I am trying to run a simple web application on Tomcat v6.0.35 in eclipse Helios. When I try to run the servlet I get the following error on browser.

Status report:"message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"
description: "The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL)"
Here is my web.xml code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>servletDemo</display-name>
```

```
<servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.lara.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servletDemo.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is html file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="DemoServlet"method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and now this is DemoServlet.java

```
package com.lara;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;      
   public DemoServlet() 
   {
    super();       
   }


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    System.out.print("1st appp demo...!!!");
}
}
```

My folder structure is like this...

[image]

The class file is also going into WEB-INF\classes foler, and also tried into web.xml with different mapping style like \servletDemo and index.html etc, but my servlet is not running on the browser althogh index file is running on the browser..:(

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[servlet]` tag which you've put on the question, wait until a black info box shows and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is because your servlet doesn't implement `doGet`: try adding the `doGet` function to the class.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    System.out.print("1st appp demo...!!!");
}
```

Comment: Should I replace doPost method with doGet or  add doGet method in servlet??

Comment: @KailashGaur you need to replace doPost with doGet , you can keep both of them in your servlet class

Comment: thanks you both.It is working,but why it is not working with doPost method?

Comment: `doPost` only responds to POST requests (such as form submissions) with a `method` attribute set to *POST*. You need to verify that your method attribute is set correctly: at first glance it looks like you need a space before *method* in your index.html, and you may have other issues.